# Add Skype contact by name with intent

Tags: android, android-intent, skype

I got the username of a Skype user.
Now, how do I start Skype (if it's installed) and go to the "search contacts" activity and pass my username I'd like to search for?

How to do this using Intent's (startActivity)

Comment: @lxx It seems nothing has changed yet. *Microsoft...*

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, without contacting the developers of the Skype application, it is impossible to know "for sure" if they have anything in place that allows this. With some digging, you could figure out a way to open up Skype's "Search Contacts" Activity (if it is, indeed, an activity), but we don't know if they implemented something that would allow you to pass a value to pre-populate the search box with. Maybe you could try contacting them?